# Can't get nftables to redirect port 80 to 8080

Tags: linux, redirect, iptables, nat, netfilter

I've tried setting up my server so it redirects traffic for port 80 to port 8080, but it doesn't work. (I get "Connection refused" errors if I telnet to port 80, and "Unable to connect" with firefox.)

I have been able to get it to work using iptables, but would prefer using nftables. Does anybody have an idea what the problem might be? (In case it's relevant, the server is running on linode.com, with a kernel provided by linode.)

I've got the following in /etc/nftables.conf:

```
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

flush ruleset

table ip fw {
        chain in {
                type filter hook input priority 0;

                # accept any localhost traffic
                iif lo accept

                # accept traffic originated from us
                ct state established,related accept

                # accept ssh, alternative http
                tcp dport { ssh, http, http-alt } ct state new counter accept

                counter drop
        }
}

table ip nat {
        chain prerouting {
                type nat hook prerouting priority 0;
                tcp dport http redirect to http-alt
        }

        chain postrouting {
                type nat hook postrouting priority 0;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're routing on localhost only, try using

```
table ip nat {
   chain output {
      type nat hook output priority 0;
      tcp dport http redirect to http-alt
   }
}
```

Some years ago I read for iptables that packets on the loop device don't traverse the prerouting chains but instead go through the output chains. That was my problem.

Comment: last line will become `ip daddr 127.0.0.1 tcp dport http redirect to http-alt` if you want to redirect ONLY packets directed to the 127.0.0.1 for example, which will allow to use `http://localhost/` instead of `http://localhost:8080/`

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean `table inet filter` instead of `table ip fw`?

If so, I had a similar problem.  Changing the ip nat `prerouting` priority to -101 got it working, but I'm not sure why.  It might be related to the default priority for [NF_IP_PRI_NAT_DST (-100): destination NAT](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Configuring_chains#Base_chain_types).  The only range that seemed to work was -101 to -200.

```
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

flush ruleset

table inet filter {
   chain input {
      type filter hook input priority 0;
      counter

      # accept any localhost traffic
      iif lo accept

      # accept traffic originated from us
      ct state {established,related} accept

      # activate the following line to accept common local services
      tcp dport { 22, 80, 443, 9443 } ct state new accept

      # accept neighbour discovery otherwise IPv6 connectivity breaks.
      ip6 nexthdr icmpv6 icmpv6 type { nd-neighbor-solicit,  nd-router-advert, nd-neighbor-advert } accept

      # count and drop any other traffic
      counter drop
   }
}

table ip nat {

   chain input {
      type nat hook input priority 0;
      counter
   }

   chain prerouting {
      type nat hook prerouting priority -101;
      counter
      tcp dport 443 counter redirect to 9443
   }

   chain postrouting {
      type nat hook postrouting priority 0;
      counter
   }
}
```

The `counter` rules make it easy to see whether the chain is even being processed; the counter values can be seen via `nft list ruleset`.